# Replace part of address in formula with string?

Tags: excel

What is a good way to replace the table name `tKomponenter` with a string `str`?

```
=[@Antal]*INDEX(tKomponenter;MATCH([@[Ingående del ID]];tKomponenter[Vårt Art no:];0);MATCH("Inköps pris";tKomponenter[#Headers];0))
```

`str` can be the name of three different tables.

Should I use Indirect or a big case function with three cases?

Comment: Is usage of VBA acceptable for your case?

Answer (score 0):

I went with an if function. There might be better solutions out there, but it worked, and would like to hear them:

```
=IF([@[Typ av del]]="Halvfabrikat";[@Antal]*INDEX(tHalvfabrikat;MATCH([@[Ingående del]];tHalvfabrikat[Vårt Art no:];0);MATCH("Utpris";tHalvfabrikat[#Headers];0));
IF([@[Typ av del]]="Komponent";[@Antal]*INDEX(Komponenter!$A$7:$S$100;MATCH([@[Ingående del]];Komponenter!$A$7:$A$100;0);MATCH("Utpris";Komponenter!$A$6:$S$6;0));
IF([@[Typ av del]]="Montering";[@Antal]*INDEX(tMonteringstider;MATCH([@[Ingående del]];tMonteringstider[Benämning];0);MATCH("Utpris";tMonteringstider[#Headers];0));"")))
```